# Divs align left and right without clear both

Tags: css, position, css-float

I have 6 divs red and blue aligned to left and right. See example:

```css
.blue{
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:41%;
    height:auto;
    background:blue;
    }
.red{
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:41%;
    height:auto;
    background:red;
    }
.demo{
    width:41%;
    height:100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="blue"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="blue"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="blue"><div class="demo"></div></div>
```

That's ok. But if content in div demo2 is heigher it will make som like this:

```css
.blue{
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:41%;
    height:auto;
    background:blue;
    }
.red{
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:41%;
    height:auto;
    background:red;
    }
.demo{
    width:41%;
    height:100px;
}
.demo2{
    width:41%;
    height:150px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="blue"><div class="demo2"></div></div>
<div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="blue"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div>
<div class="blue"><div class="demo"></div></div>
```

Unfortunatelly I cant include them to the two parent divs (e.g. #left, #right) because this boxes need to be sorted chronically.

I tried to use position/fixed/absolute/ but nothing happens.

Comment: clear:left to be set on the .blue divs isn't a good thingy?

Comment: @GL.awog Not working. It's a blank space betwen first red div and second red div. I need it without blank space. See example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL97ct1u/)

Comment: yep it's normal for floats on the same row not to have equal heights. not achievable without wrapping divs in a row and adjusting flex display, i'm afraid. http://jsfiddle.net/oL97ct1u/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create html in following way

```css
    .parent{ float: left; height: auto; width: 100%; margin-bottom:10px; }
    
    .blue{ float:left; width:41%; height:100%; background:blue; } 
    
    .red{ float:right; width:41%; height:100%; background:red; } 
    
    .demo{ width:41%; height:100px; } 
    
    .demo2{ width:41%; height:150px; }
```

```html
    <div class='parent' style='height:150px'> 
      <div class="blue"><div class="demo2"></div></div> 
      <div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div> 
    </div> 

    <div class='parent'> 
      <div class="blue"><div class="demo"></div></div> 
      <div class="red"><div class="demo"></div></div> 
    </div>
```

Hope this works, reply in case of query

Comment: FYI  Quote: Unfortunatelly I cant include them to the two parent divs

Comment: @TimDev But i am not including them to two different parents, he mean to say #left parent and #right parent, but i have created parent with left and right divs, to keep it in **chronically** order. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I need to have divs sorted chronically without blank space.

Comment: @BhupenderKeswani Your solution does match the condition!  I was thrown of because of the  `e.g.`. Your answer indeed prove his condition and reasoning to be wrong.   But I guess the blank space is another condition, please add it in your question.

Comment: @TimDev Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @bulldozer I am working on it. for now work around is add inline height 150px to parent.div containing demo2 div.